# Determine all integers $i$ such that $(i-29)(i+29)$ is a square number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

> Determine all integers $i$ such that 
>   $$(i-29)(i+29)$$ 
>   is a square number.

I’ve tried some substitutions but none of them worked...
I think that the only solutions are $i=\pm 29$, but I still don’t know how to prove it.

Comment: How about $i=421$ ...

Comment: @MattiP. Related to Pythagorean triple $421^2 = 420^2+29^2$. Any odd positive number is the difference between consecutive squares, for $2N+1=(N+1)^2-N^2$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hint: $$i^2-29^2=j^2\implies (i-j)(i+j)= 29^2$$

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
i+j & i-j & 2i& i \\
\hline
1& 29^2 & 1+29^2 &421\\
29&29&58&29\\
29^2&1& 1+29^2& 421\\
-1& -29^2 & -1-29^2 &-421\\
-29&-29&-58&-29\\
-29^2&-1& -1-29^2&-421
\end{array}
$$

Comment: $29^2$ is a semiprime number. There are only six ways to decompose it into two integer parts. Only the first two columns of the table are relevant to the decomposition of $29^2$. The last two  are finding $i$ so you can find $j$.